# Skipping first slide in Nivoslider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, nivo-slider

I'm using **Nivoslider Version 3.1** on a small WordPress site I am building.

I was wondering if there is a way I can tell Nivoslider to **always** ignore Slide 1.

So if my HTML is:

```
<div id="slider" class="slider nivoSlider">
<img src="1.jpg" /> <!-- Ignore this ALWAYS -->
<img src="2.jpg" />
<img src="3.jpg" />
<img src="4.jpg" />
</div>
```

So, the Slider will **always start at 2.jpg** & will **never show 1.jpg**. Is this possible?

Here is the [Nivoslider Demo](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/demos/) for reference.

It's an odd workaround, I agree, but my current implementation of the Slider doesn't work when I use a foreach loop to populate the slider. It does populate it, but the slider gets stuck on "loading".

For the record, here's my current implementation of it:

```
<div id="slider" class="slider nivoSlider">
                <?php
                    $id = get_the_ID();
                    $custom_fields = get_post_custom($id);
                    $my_custom_field = $custom_fields['img1'];
                    foreach ( $my_custom_field as $key => $value ) {
                        echo '<img src="/wp-content/themes/boilerplate/images/csg-50c8a86d6bfc0.png" height="350" width="620">';
                    }
                ?>
                </div>
```

Many thanks for any help that can be given with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the particular version of nivoslider you have downloaded/ particular edits you may have made to it:

Look for slide-show.js

and edit the line

```
startSlide: 0, // Set starting Slide (0 index)
```

To skip it on the first loop

And...(I'm going out on a limb here)

In jquery.nivo.slider edit the function...

```
$.fn.nivoSlider = function(options) {

    //Defaults are below
    var settings = $.extend({}, $.fn.nivoSlider.defaults, options);

    return this.each(function() {
        //Useful variables. Play carefully.
        var vars = {
            currentSlide: 0,
            currentImage: '',
            totalSlides: 0,
            randAnim: '',
            running: false,
            paused: false,
            stop:false
        };
```

Such that you hardcode the absolute number of slides and that it should restart the loop before reaching 1.jpg.

Not certain if this will work - hardcoding such elements like this would generally not be a good idea; you would also want to remove user controls to prevent manual navigation to that slide.

It does beg the question: why would you want to include a slide that you never want to be displayed?

Comment: Brilliant comment!!!

I will try this right now.

I should have said, I'm on **version 3.1**

Comment: I add it in as currently the Slideshow doesn't seem to operate without it initially having at least 1 `<img>` tag in there. 
I'm guessing it takes too long to process the `foreach` loop and so nivo gets confused. I guess :)
I'll try your amendments :)

Comment: Editing `startSlide: 1,` worked great. Unfortunately the other alts didn't work for me. It's still stuck on 'loading' despite now having 3 `<img>` tags in there. 1 is always there and 2 from the foreach loop :'(

Comment: Possibly call the function as being done in this http://webdesignandsuch.com/make-the-jquery-nivo-slider-stop-after-one-loop/ ... but instead of calling it to stop, call it to change the current slide after iteration? Calling the function seems to allow you to edit the var vars booleans and integers

Comment: Hi Duncan, apologies for my delay. I think you *may* be onto something here. I'll try mess around with this and will keep you posted. Thanks for the link :-)

Answer (score -1):

above didn't work for me.. what *did* work for me (to skip the 4th image) was this:

```
   $('#slider').nivoSlider({
       prevText: '',
       nextText: '',
       controlNav: false,
       beforeChange: function ()
       {
           var current = $('#slider').data('nivo:vars').currentSlide;
           //if the currentIndex = 2, the next will be 3, which is the fourth image, 
           //which is the one I wanted to skip
           if(current == 2)
           {
               $('#slider').data('nivo:vars').currentSlide = 3;
           }
       }
   });
```

for the first image you should probably say if current == * last-index *  { ... currentSlide = 0 }